# R get the difference between two set date on the same row in a data frame

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to write a code that gets the months difference of two dates in the same row. The idea is to get the difference of the ending date of one group from the starting date of another group.

This is my data frame:

```
ID  Groups  Date
110     2   17/03/2012
110     2   29/03/2013
110     3   16/08/2013
110     3   05/02/2014
110     5   25/09/2014
110     5   26/11/2014
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
ID  Months
110     4       
110     7
```

Comment: `two dates on the same row` is not clear.  There is only date per row in the example

Comment: @ akrun, Is the changed title okay now?

Comment: How you are calculating the Months i.e  which dates you take the difference to get t5 and 7

Comment: Please only use tags that are relevant. You add no code to your question but insist on tagging it with `tidyverse`. The tag only applies to questions with  more  than one `tidyverse` package used.

Comment: @ akrun, In the table there are three different groups right, I want to take the end date of the first group from the starting date of the second group.

Comment: May be you need to get the `lag` of the 'Date' and do the difference after grouping by 'Groups'

Comment: something like `df1 %>% mutate(Date = dmy(Date), DateN = lead(Date)) %>% group_by(ID, Groups) %>% summarise(Date1 = first(DateN), Date2 = last(DateN)) %>% na.omit %>% transmute(Months = as.numeric(interval(Date1, Date2) %/% months(1)))`

Comment: The difference I get between the `29/03/2013` and `16/08/2013` is 4 monthss

Comment: Yeah, thanks that worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, then create the `lead` of 'Date' as a new column, grouped by 'ID', 'Groups', `summarise` to get the `interval` difference between the `first` and `last` elements from the `lead` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Date =lead(dmy(Date))) %>% 
   group_by(ID, Groups) %>% 
   summarise(Date1 = first(Date), Date2 = last(Date)) %>%
   na.omit %>%
   transmute(Months = as.numeric(interval(Date1, Date2) %/% months(1)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   ID [1]
#     ID Months
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1   110      4
#2   110      7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L), Groups = c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L), Date = c("17/03/2012", "29/03/2013", "16/08/2013", 
"05/02/2014", "25/09/2014", "26/11/2014")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```